# What does + mean in the string returned by Type.ToString()?

Tags: c#

Calling ToString() on some Type objects returns a value containing a +.

eg. The program below outputs:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+RangeIterator

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestNS
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var test = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What does the + symbol mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `RangeIterator` is a nested class of `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

In general, the pattern for the value returned by `Type.ToString()` for nested classes is:

```
Namespace.OuterClass+NestedClass
```